# Basic trigonometry in Java

Tags: java, trigonometry

I've been struggling around with this problem for a couple of days, so after alot of googling I decided to ask here instead.

Anyway, I need to use the `Math.tan()` method, but it doesn't work really as I want. Becase if I set up an double variable: `double i = opposite/adjacent` and then use the `Math.tan()` method on that, it just returns 0.0! For example:

```
double i = 480/640;
System.out.println(Math.tan(i));
```

But it still returns zero! I read that the `Math.tan()` method only returns the "Radian" value. But because of that it should'nt return zero? Or am I wrong? I know that if i use a real calculator and do tan(480/640) it will return what I want.

So I hope someone understands me and wants to help me!
Thanks in advance! (Btw I'm sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `int` calculations, `480/640` is `0`. So the result of `i` will be `0.0`.

You need to write `double i = 480.0/640;` (At least one of the numbers has to be written as a `double`).

You can also write: `double a = 480, b = 640;` and then if you write `double i = a/b;` you'll get good result.

Comment: Thanks dude! That wasn't really the first thing I tought of, so thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

When you do maths without casts Java will implicitly make literals integers first - in your case this will indeed result in 0.

Cast the values before doing your maths and it'll be fine:

```
    double i = 480D/640D;
    System.out.println(i);
```

or

```
    double i = (double)480/(double)640;
    System.out.println(i);
```

or

```
    double numerator = 480;
    double denominator = 640;
    double i = numerator / denominator;
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

write `double i = 480.0/640.0;` the `480/640` is understood as an integer division, so gives 0

Answer (score 1):

Change in

double i = (double) 480/640;